# Marshal Unmarshal JSON struct problems causing REST request to fail

Tags: json, go, marshalling, unmarshalling

I am updating the problem statement since input from nipuna, who solved the problem. The question is better described as, "why does unmarshal, then marshal of JSON result in changes to the JSON that are not compatible with a REST API request?" The reason discovered, and that I could not have discovered alone, were that the text fields sometimes needed to be included and sometimes omitted in a JSON array, and the marshal data structure did not support omitting them. The structure did use the term "omitempty" for these fields, so it could be believed this directive would omit them, however that is not sufficient. I also needed for the text fields to be pointers. The original problem description follows below. **The final data structure uses both "omitempty" for the text fields and also makes the anonymous struct a pointer.** (Please see the accepted answer)

I have a REST request that fails when I use Go Unmarshal / Marshal but it works on the same JSON data from a file. I have verified that the resulting []byte from reading the file is different if I take that exact []byte and roundtrip UnMarshal / Marshal it. As a result, my REST request fails. Here it is diagramatically: file json -> []byte = set A of bytes. file json -> []byte -> UnMarshal -> Marshal -> []byte = set B of bytes. Set A of bytes != set B of bytes. I would not care except that I need to modify the data in the structure of Go, then Marshal it, however the byte changes that I do not understand causes the request to fail.

Here is test code:

```
type SlackRequestData struct {
    Blocks []struct {
        BlockID  string `json:"block_id"`
        Elements []struct {
            ActionID string `json:"action_id"`
            Style    string `json:"style"`
            Text     struct {
                Text string `json:"text"`
                Type string `json:"type"`
            } `json:"text"`
            Type  string `json:"type"`
            Value string `json:"value"`
        } `json:"elements"`
        Text struct {
            Text string `json:"text"`
            Type string `json:"type"`
        } `json:"text"`
        Type string `json:"type"`
    } `json:"blocks"`
}

func MarshalFailTest(){
    bytes_io, err := ioutil.ReadFile("../../slack/slack-message.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %+v\n", err) // handle err
    }
    new_req := SlackRequestData{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(bytes_io, &new_req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %+v\n", err) // handle err
    }
    new_json, err := json.Marshal(new_req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %+v\n", err) // handle err
    }
    fmt.Printf("New req:\n%+v\n", new_req)
    fmt.Printf("New Json:\n%+v\n", new_json)
    fmt.Printf("Bytes:\n%+v\n", bytes_io)
}
```

Here is the json file data:

```
{
  "blocks": [{
    "type": "section",
    "text": {
      "type": "mrkdwn",
      "text": "Service Is Ready. Now?"
    }
  },
    {
      "type": "actions",
      "block_id": "deploy_id",
      "elements": [{
        "type": "button",
      "action_id": "yes_button",
        "text": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "Yes"
          },
        "style": "danger",
        "value": "yes"
      },
    {
      "type": "button",
      "action_id": "yes_toll_button",
      "text": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Yes To All"
      },
      "style": "danger",
      "value": "yes"
    },
      {
        "type": "button",
      "action_id": "no_button",
        "text": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "No"
        },
        "style": "primary",
      "value": "no"
      },
    {
      "type": "button",
      "action_id": "no_toall_button",
      "text": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "No To All"
      },
      "style": "primary",
      "value": "no"
    }]
    }]
}
```

Note that I used several converters to take the file json and create the SlackRequestData struct, and the UnMarshal appears to work perfectly as the struct in the debugger has all the data in the right place. There are no errors with Marshal / UnMarshal either. So why does the []byte differ?

The data sets are large, so I'll just share the first line of each set here.
Set A:
[123 10 32 32 34 98 108 111 99 107 115 34 58 32 91 123 10 32 32 32 32 34 116 121 112 101 34 58 32 34 115 101 99 116 105 111 110 34 44 10 32 32 32 32 34
Set B:
[123 34 98 108 111 99 107 115 34 58 91 123 34 98 108 111 99 107 95 105 100 34 58 34 34 44 34 101 108 101 109 101 110 116 115 34 58 110 117 108 108 44

Here are the two sets converted from []byte to strings, as this is quite interesting too. The set A keeps whitespace, the set B has no whitespace but also the elements have been rearranged. I wonder if the struct is not correct? However I've been using this technique of using converters to create structs out of json and they have worked well to this point.

Set A:

```
{
  "blocks": [{
    "type": "section",
    "text": {
      "type": "mrkdwn",
      "text": "Service Is Ready. Now?"
    }
  },
    {
      "type": "actions",
      "block_id": "deploy_id",
      "elements": [{
        "type": "button",
      "action_id": "yes_button",
        "text": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "Yes"
          },
        "style": "danger",
        "value": "yes"
      },
    {
      "type": "button",
      "action_id": "yes_toll_button",
      "text": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Yes To All"
      },
      "style": "danger",
      "value": "yes"
    },
      {
        "type": "button",
      "action_id": "no_button",
        "text": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "No"
        },
        "style": "primary",
      "value": "no"
      },
    {
      "type": "button",
      "action_id": "no_toall_button",
      "text": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "No To All"
      },
      "style": "primary",
      "value": "no"
    }]
    }]
}
```

Set B:

```
{"blocks":[{"block_id":"","elements":null,"text":{"text":"Service Is Ready. Now?","type":"mrkdwn"},"type":"section"},{"block_id":"deploy_id","elements":[{"action_id":"yes_button","style":"danger","text":{"text":"Yes","type":"plain_text"},"type":"button","value":"yes"},{"action_id":"yes_toll_button","style":"danger","text":{"text":"Yes To All","type":"plain_text"},"type":"button","value":"yes"},{"action_id":"no_button","style":"primary","text":{"text":"No","type":"plain_text"},"type":"button","value":"no"},{"action_id":"no_toall_button","style":"primary","text":{"text":"No To All","type":"plain_text"},"type":"button","value":"no"}],"text":{"text":"","type":""},"type":"actions"}]}
```

nipuna suggested I try using beautify of the JSON so I did this and there is the string version of the []byte for each set.
Set A:

```
{
  "blocks": [{
    "type": "section",
    "text": {
      "type": "mrkdwn",
      "text": "Service Is Ready. Now?"
    }
  },
    {
      "type": "actions",
      "block_id": "deploy_id",
      "elements": [{
        "type": "button",
      "action_id": "yes_button",
        "text": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "Yes"
          },
        "style": "danger",
        "value": "yes"
      },
    {
      "type": "button",
      "action_id": "yes_toll_button",
      "text": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Yes To All"
      },
      "style": "danger",
      "value": "yes"
    },
      {
        "type": "button",
      "action_id": "no_button",
        "text": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "No"
        },
        "style": "primary",
      "value": "no"
      },
    {
      "type": "button",
      "action_id": "no_toall_button",
      "text": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "No To All"
      },
      "style": "primary",
      "value": "no"
    }]
    }]
}
```

Set B:

```
{
  "blocks": [
    {
      "block_id": "",
      "elements": null,
      "text": {
        "text": "Service Is Ready. Now?",
        "type": "mrkdwn"
      },
      "type": "section"
    },
    {
      "block_id": "deploy_id",
      "elements": [
        {
          "action_id": "yes_button",
          "style": "danger",
          "text": {
            "text": "Yes",
            "type": "plain_text"
          },
          "type": "button",
          "value": "yes"
        },
        {
          "action_id": "yes_toll_button",
          "style": "danger",
          "text": {
            "text": "Yes To All",
            "type": "plain_text"
          },
          "type": "button",
          "value": "yes"
        },
        {
          "action_id": "no_button",
          "style": "primary",
          "text": {
            "text": "No",
            "type": "plain_text"
          },
          "type": "button",
          "value": "no"
        },
        {
          "action_id": "no_toall_button",
          "style": "primary",
          "text": {
            "text": "No To All",
            "type": "plain_text"
          },
          "type": "button",
          "value": "no"
        }
      ],
      "text": {
        "text": "",
        "type": ""
      },
      "type": "actions"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the difference yourself? Just compare it element by element?

Comment: Yes, here are the data sets (I'll add the first line of each set in the original post).

Comment: So, have you found the difference? Have you tried to turn them to strings to see why it happens? It should be instantly obvious what's the difference between `123 10 32 32 34` and `123 34` is it?

Comment: I think problem is in json indenting. Please beautify your json string in the file and marshal json with indent.

Comment: I have done as you suggested and the request still fails. I do see some small whitespace differences between the two, but can that really explain the failure? I thought JSON was robust to whitespace differences?

Comment: I will add the results with json beautify to the original post now.

Comment: JSON is robust to whitespace differences. It's not obvious though why you think marshalling should keep the original formatting. You also should make some fields optional (through `omitempty` and a pointer if you don't want them to set to zero values)

Comment: Well my goal is not to keep original formatting, but to have the reception of the JSON have the same meaning to the far end server. I just want the REST request to act the same way as if I had not UnMarshal / Marshalled the data set. Is that not a reasonable expectation? It is for me like saying 2+2=1+1+2 but 2+2=2+1+1 I were to get a different answer? I expect round-trip marshalling of JSON to be seen in the same light. Now I do see an interesting difference in field ordering, so I'm more thinking the structure is doing something to the JSON that the receiver of the JSON does not like?

Comment: It's difficult to understand your problem but I'm not sure why. It should be simple to do the round trip without loss OR to work out where the loss occurs.  Maybe the clue is in "byte changes that I do not understand causes the request to fail" - what error do you get?  Another idea is to do some simple experiments with JSON marshalling and unmarshalling and if you encounter something you don't understand post a simple question with short well-formated JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see following differences and I have mention some suggestions.

**Optional fields**

Your data consist of array of `blocks`, in first block, there is only two fields `text` and `type` and in second block there is all other fields but no `text`. So that `text` is optional and it need to be omit when it is an empty struct. So you need to define your `SlackRequestData` with `omitempty` and pointer type to `Text` fields.

Suggested `SlackRequestData` struct is something like below.

```
type Text struct {
    Type string `json:"type,omitempty"`
    Text string `json:"text,omitempty"`
}

type SlackRequestData struct {
    Blocks []struct {
        BlockID  string `json:"block_id,omitempty"`
        Elements []struct {
            ActionID string `json:"action_id,omitempty"`
            Style    string `json:"style,omitempty"`
            Text     *Text `json:"text,omitempty"`
            Type  string `json:"type,omitempty"`
            Value string `json:"value,omitempty"`
        } `json:"elements,omitempty"`
        Text *Text `json:"text,omitempty"`
        Type string `json:"type,omitempty"`
    } `json:"blocks,omitempty"`
}
```

**Marshalled Data Order**

your file json data's field order and `SlackRequestData`'s field order is different. So obviously that marshalled string and file string is different. json marshalling not guarantees that order when marshalling as mentiond in [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27179). So if you need to compare those two, please sort those bytes in someway and compare.

**Json Indent**

In your file data is somewhat json beautified data and json marshal return compacted output. If you need to get same marshal output, you need to use [MarshalIndent](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#MarshalIndent) and do indent you used in file.

So if you need to compare both things, marshal with `omitempty`, sort both results (file byte array and json marshalled byte array). and remove whitespaces and then compare. You can get correct same result.

Comment: This looks very promising! I was noticing something similar, but did not know how to deal with the empty strings. I will work on this tomorrow (after late night working on this) and see if this will resolve the issue. I agree that the structure used in Marshalling is the source of the problem.

Comment: `The "omitempty" option specifies that the field should be omitted from the encoding if the field has an empty value, defined as false, 0, a nil pointer, a nil interface value, and any empty array, slice, map, or string.` Empty strings will omit by `omitempty` like mentioned above in [godoc](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json). And if you need to validate something like `*required`, you can use string pointers for all string fields in struct.

Comment: That worked but I also made another adjustment in the order of some of the fields so it matches the other JSON exactly. I will put the final struct I used in the posting section. Thanks so much nipuna!!

Comment: It's my pleasure :-)